# Processing of MSSQL non-recursive CTE

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression

I would like to know as to How exactly a CTE is processed when used in a query. For a VIEW, I know that it's query is merged with the main query and the optimiser then parses and builds the plan for the merged query. And which is why sometimes VIEWS are not recommended as they can cause performance degradation if they have many tables to add to the tables in the main query itself.

Is CTE processed in the same way?

Comment: This might help: http://explainextended.com/2009/11/18/sql-server-are-the-recursive-ctes-really-set-based/

Comment: Thanks for your link. But it discusses recursive CTEs only. I want to know how a non-recursive CTE is processed.

Answer (score 0):

I setup a SQL Fiddle that shows how the execution plans can be identical for simple situations (http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a1ea2/1/0).

Generally without more details to your specifics, non-recursive CTEs behave the same as Views or Sub-Queries. This assumes you are not indexing views which would result in statistics being stored and offering advantages in query performance with the right non-clustered indexes.